# Flask-SocketIO Not Working On Apache/WSGI

Tags: python, apache, flask, gevent-socketio, flask-socketio

I have used the following example code from http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent/page/4 and this works fine when I run it using the test server e.g. `python myapp.py` I can connect to it and send messages

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('my event', namespace='/test')
def test_message(message):
    emit('my response', {'data': message['data']})

@socketio.on('my broadcast event', namespace='/test')
def test_message(message):
    emit('my response', {'data': message['data']}, broadcast=True)

@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/test')
def test_connect():
    emit('my response', {'data': 'Connected'})

@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/test')
def test_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

The problem is when I move this same code to a server that is using Apache to serve Flask I get errors.

```
RuntimeError: You need to use a gevent-socketio server.
```

Config file for Apache host is:

```
 WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
 WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/public/flaskApp/flaskApp.wsgi

 <Location /var/www/public/flaskApp/flaskApp/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

Is it possible to run SocketIO/Flask and have it work through Apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your */var/www/public/flaskApp/flaskApp.wsgi* file that Apache is running your app through doesn't use a socketio-capable server.

The tutorial you're reading states

> The extension is initialized in the usual way, but to simplify the start up of the server a custom `run()` method is provided by the extension. This method starts gevent, the only supported web server. Using gunicorn with a gevent worker should also work.

The [uWSGI documentation](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Gevent.html#running-uwsgi-in-gevent-mode) has a section on running in gevent mode, but [Miguel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/904393/miguel) commented:

> uwsgi does not work with this extension either, because it does not allow a custom gevent loop to be used. Gunicorn does work, the command is in the documentation.

So, Gunicorn. From [the docs](http://flask-socketio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#deployment):

> An alternative is to use gunicorn as web server, using the worker class provided by gevent-socketio. The command line that starts the server in this way is shown below:
>
> ```
> gunicorn --worker-class socketio.sgunicorn.GeventSocketIOWorker module:app
> ```

In short, ensure that you're running with something that provides the gevent worker.

Comment: uwsgi does not work with this extension either, because it does not allow a custom gevent loop to be used. Gunicorn does work, the command is in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Gunicorn is what I use myself.

Comment: @Miguel I thought that might be the case. I did read the documentation but it just seemed odd that their was no way to somehow proxy through Apache to Flask to handle the socketio.

Comment: @user4143585 yes, but the problem is that this is outside of the wsgi spec, which is what apache/uwsgi implement.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution? I am also running into the same problem.